# Use hs-minor-mode where it's not supported

Tags: eshell, code-folding, hideshow

I'd like to use `hs-minor-mode` is some buffers that are not related code editing, but still includes some structured data which I'd like to fold.

For instance, in `eshell` I run a program with some debug output in JSON and it would be neat if I could collapse it to focus on specific fields, in regular code buffer I can do that, but for `eshell` it says that it "doesn't support Hideshow Minor Mode".

Is there any way to direct it with some syntax hints or maybe there are some smaller building blocks in Emacs to make my customized Hideshow for such cases?

Answer (score 1):

There are two variables that could help you, which you can set when starting an eshell buffer:

```lisp
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook #'outline-minor-mode)
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
            (lambda () (setq-local page-delimiter eshell-prompt-regexp
                              outline-regexp eshell-prompt-regexp)))
```

With `outline-regexp` you can fold/unfold commands where each prompt serves as a 'heading'.

By setting the page delimiter to your prompt regexp, you can easily browse between different command outputs or easily narrow to a 'page' (`C-x n p`)

Comment: This is something I can work with, thanks!

I guess it's not suitable for things like folding `key` inside `{yeet: 1337, key: { ... } }` in one line, right?